# How can I change the style of input inside TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, direction

I used React-Admin `TextInput` and I am trying to create a left-to-right input. I used `stylish-pugin-rtl` package which makes all styled-components right-to-left (probably using scripts). Now I want to exclude one input. Overriding it using `sx` isn't effective, and it still remains `rtl`;

I just can change the direction using the style attr of input, however I don't know how to access it. TextInput creates a div and an input inside it:

```
// LTRTextInput.js
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-admin';

const LTRTextInput = ({ ...props }) => {
    return (
        <TextInput
            {...props}
            // Use sx prop to apply styles
            sx={{
                '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
                    backgroundColor:'red',
                    direction: 'ltr !important', // It doesn't work
                },
            }}
            // need to change the style of input inside TextInput
        />
    );  
};
```

Comment: Could you use devtools to inspect the conflicting style?

Comment: in devtools the diretion of  the div element is rtl and `sx` isn't applied on it probably because of plugin which changes direction at runtime, I want to test style, but style of innert input elment.

Comment: Could you potentially use `className` instead with some global CSS? Kind of defeats the points of styledcomponents but if your plugin is overriding it this could be a workaround.